# using Expression-bodied members improve some performance?

Tags: c#

I trying to find some information about the 'Expression-bodied members' - to know if using the 'Expression-bodied members' ( beside simple properties or method )  improve some performance of the application

( maybe after compile the Expression-bodied members is call as inline method and this can improve some performance ( just an option ) )

but i can't find any explain to this.

anyone know if using the Expression-bodied members is just for better code or it also make some better performance ?

Comment: Why don't you just measure it?

Comment: @PeterB i did .. but on simple app i don't see any different

Comment: What makes you think these "improve performance"? Improve performance compared to what? What do you mean by "improve performance"?

Comment: Expression-bodied members are syntactical sugar, exactly equivalent to a method written out in full. They have no effect on performance whatsoever.

Comment: @Liam because using properties ( that less 16 bit ) the calling properties is inline

Comment: Note the famous Donald Knuth quote *"Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: **premature optimization is the root of all evil**. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%."*

Comment: my application deals with video and the performance are very impotent - so this was simple question .. because i can't find any answer be measure it.

Comment: For all your microbenchmarking needs, there's [BenchmarkDotNet](https://benchmarkdotnet.org/). However, an even simpler approach in this case is to use LINQPad and compare the resulting IL. If the IL of two pieces of code is identical, you don't need to do any further performance testing.

Comment: lol, impotent. Yes, in this case that is apt. The performance of this is likely very *impotent*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very often it is used just to write shorter (thus writting code faster?) and more readable code.

But trying to force `=>` whenever you can may have negative effect on readability of yours code.

Comment: shorter != faster. C# is a compiled language, nothing that your write gets directly ran ever

Comment: @Liam by "faster" I meant time spent on writting code. My bad cuz I didnt express myself properly.

Comment: @Liam Because I didnt meant performance. I just wanted to answer that part ``anyone know if using the Expression-bodied members is just for better code ``

Comment: Describe "better"?

Comment: @Liam shorter (in most cases), easier to maintain, with better readability.

Comment: @Liam In fact there´s no general rule what "performance" means. Development-speed is of course also a possible measure.

Comment: Ok, I'll concede that this is a form of performance :)